# Como identificar o erro neste código?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
LadodoQuadrado = input("Digite o valor correspondente ao lado de um quadrado: ")

variavel = float(LadodoQuadrado)

x = LadodoQuadrado * 4
    
y = LadodoQuadrado ^ 2
    
print("perímetro:", x, "área:", y)
```

Quando eu tendo rodar o programa, diz "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" nas variáveis, cada hora muda a variável que dá erro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro de sintaxe é porque falta um parêntese no final de `input`.

Depois de resolver este erro, o script ainda vai retornar outro erro

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'int'

Isto porque o retorno de `input` é uma `string`, ou seja, é preciso converter a entrada do usuário para um número e só depois tentar fazer alguma operação matemática com a mesma.

Eu coloquei uma conversão direta usando `int(input(""))`, porém, tenha em mente que isso vai causar um erro se o usuário entrar com qualquer valor que não seja propriamente um número (se a entreda for "Walkyrien", por exemplo).

```
LadodoQuadrado = int(input("Digite o valor correspondente ao lado de um quadrado: "))
variavel = float(LadodoQuadrado)

x = LadodoQuadrado * 4

y = LadodoQuadrado ^ 2

print("perímetro:", x, "área:", y)
```

---

Pra fins de conhecimento, uma maneira de fazer isto tratando a entrada do usuário

```
strEntrada = input("Digite o valor correspondente ao lado de um quadrado: ")

try:
    LadodoQuadrado = int(strEntrada)
except ValueError:
    print('entre com um número inteiro')
    exit()

variavel = float(LadodoQuadrado)

x = LadodoQuadrado * 4

y = LadodoQuadrado ^ 2

print("perímetro:", x, "área:", y)
```

Answer (score 0):

O operador de potenciação no Python não é "^", e sim "**" ou pow (x, y) se você quiser usar a função da biblioteca math.